# Golang abstracted Interface Slice conversion

Tags: go

I have a list of objects (olievere/Elastic SearchResult.Hits to be exact). Each of these has a `json.RawMessage` object and I'm looking to create an abstractable method that takes in an interface slice of any struct, Unmarshal's each individual hits' `json.RawMessage` into said struct, and appends it to the passed in `[]interface`.

This func is not supposed to have any logic or insight into the desired business layer struct, and the DB Call is interfaced pretty heavily, and as such has no visibility into the Elastic package mentioned above. Example of what I was attempting to do...

```
foo.go    
import (bar, package)
type TestStruct struct {    
    Slice []*package.Struct // package.Struct has a value of Source which is a    
                            // json.RawMessage    
}    

func GetData() bar.Test {
    return &TestStruct{*package.GetData()}
}

func (result TestStruct) UnmarshalStruct(v []interface{}) {    
    for _, singleStruct := range result.Slice {     
        append(json.Unmarshal(singleStruct, &v))
    }
```

Second File

```
bar.go
type Handler interface {
    GetData() Test
}

type Test interface {
    UnmarshalStruct
}

type OtherType struct {
   foo string
   bar string
} 

func RetrieveData() []OtherType {
    handler := New(Handler)
    test := handler.GetData()
    var typeSlice []OtherType    
    test.UnmarshalStruct(&typeSlice)
}
```

**I'm looking to hand something of type `[]OtherType`, or any other new struct I decide to create, to `UnmarshalStruct`, and have it return to me that same struct, just full of data**

As an example, I have two different types of data I'll be searching for from Elastic. I will be receiving a list of ONE of the following two objects.

```
{ 'foo': '',
  'id': 
}
```

And in a different index

```
{ 'bar': '',
  'baz': '',
  'eee': ''
}
```

Each of these will naturally require two different structs.
However, I desire a single method to be able to decode either of these lists. I'll be given below, and using the same function I want to be able to convert this to a `bar` struct, and the other type to a `foo` struct.

```
{ 'source': [
    { 'bar': '',
      'baz': '',
      'eee': ''
    },
    { 'bar': '',
      'baz': '',
      'eee': ''
    },
    { 'bar': '',
      'baz': '',
      'eee': ''
    }    
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question. Are you having a problem with: https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface?

Comment: Yes, please give some more details on the problem that you're having.

Comment: Updated in bold. I'm looking to hand something of type []OtherType, or any other new struct I decide to create, to UnmarshalStruct, and have it return to me that same struct, just full of data

Comment: Posted json but the question is getting pretty convoluted, as I feel I'm repeating the same thing. Simply put, I want a generic func that I give an interface slice of an instantiated struct (let's call it A). It will then fill A, and I can return A from the original calling func.

Comment: so the question is: given a list of heterogenous json objects, what function can i write to magically unmarshal each json object into the correct struct type without telling the function which struct types to expect beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no way to do what you want without reflection. I would personally structure this differently, so that you unmarshal into more generic types, like a `map[string]string`, or as @ThunderCat shows, get rid of the intermediary state and unamrshal directly into the correct types. But it can be done...

(I moved the json.RawMessage directly into TestStruct to get rid of one level of indirection and make the example more clear)

```
type TestStruct struct {
    Slice []json.RawMessage
}

func (t TestStruct) UnmarshalStruct(v interface{}) error {
    // get the a Value for the underlying slice
    slice := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()
    // make sure we have adequate capacity
    slice.Set(reflect.MakeSlice(slice.Type(), len(t.Slice), len(t.Slice)))

    for i, val := range t.Slice {
        err := json.Unmarshal(val, slice.Index(i).Addr().Interface())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

You can then call it like so

```
var others []OtherType
err := ts.UnmarshalStruct(&others)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/dgly2OOXDG

Comment: This is perfect, and is exactly what I was looking for. I wanted this to be as abstract as possible for my particular architecture constraints, perhaps I have this built weirdly in another sense, but this is spot on. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to unmarshal data to slices of two types:

```
type A struct {
  Foo string `json:"foo"`
  ID string `json:"id"`
}

type B struct {
   Bar string `json:"bar"`
   Baz string `json:"baz"`
   Eee string `json:"eee"`
}
```

from a [SearchHit Source](https://godoc.org/github.com/olivere/elastic#SearchHit.Source).

The JSON package can do most of the work for you:

```
func executeQuery(q Query, v interface{}) error {
   // Get a SearchHit. I am making this up. 
   // I have no idea how the package works.
   searchHit, err := getHit(q) 
   if err != nil {
      return err
   }
   // This is the important part. Convert the raw message to 
   // a slice of bytes and decode to the caller's slice.
   return json.Unmarshal([]byte(*searchHit.Source), v)
}
```

You can call this function to decode to a slice of the types or a slice of pointers to the types.

```
// Slice of type
var s1 []TypeA
if err := executeQuery(q1, &s1); err != nil {
    // handle error
}

// Slice of pointer to type
var s2 []*TypeB
if err := error(q2, &s2); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
```

I know that this is not a direct answer to the question, but this is how this scenario is typically handled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is easy to do. In the [Raw Message Example](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) in the godocs they use a value within the json, "Space" in their example, to determine which struct type to unmarshal into.

For this to work, the function would have to have some way of getting every struct that has been defined ever for the program, and then it would have to examine each json object and compare it to each struct using reflection to figure out which type it most likely is. And what if there are multiple structs that "could be it"? Then conflict resolution complicates things.

In short, I don't think you can do this.